# How can I check the current situation in Budapest train station?

Tags: trains, event-based-effects, delays, budapest, refugees

As most of you know right now Budapest train station is crowded with a lot of refugees coming from Syria and there have been some [incidents](http://edition.cnn.com/2015/09/01/europe/europe-migrant-crisis/) related to the refugees trying to get out of Budapest.

I'm traveling to Budapest in two weeks time and I wonder if it will be easy to get into the city by train. As can be seen in the link that I posted before there have been some delays but I just found those related to the incidents that took place on Thursday. I couldn't find any more info regarding the actual situation of the train station.

**Are there any major delays regarding trains coming into Budapest? Is there any website where I can check the situation?**

To provide further information I am an EU citizen and I was planning to get into Budapest taking a train from Zagreb.

Comment: It's changing a lot, might be best to ask for a resource to check the situation rather than about the current situation or a prediction of what could be the situation in two weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be headed that way myself as part of a relief mission for the [JCWI](http://www.jcwi.org.uk/).  I would recommend the [live Budapest feed on Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=Budapest&src=tyah)...

[image]

It is not an 'official' source and the feed is intermixed with comments that some may find indecorous (hence my redaction).  But there is enough 'live' information to make it worthwhile.  The feed includes 'live' updates from the BBC and other credible sources.

You may also find that the [feed for Budapest Trains](https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=Budapest%20trains&src=typd) contains very specific information about what to expect on a moment-by-moment basis...

[image]